# PHP CSV import, but without first two lines and a cut of infos

Tags: php, csv

Hellos,

I would like to do a simple telephone list. The csv data I do get from a csv list from an active directory powershell export.

the csv is comma seperated and it's looking that way:

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
name,"officephone"
firstnameA, lastnameA,"+49 12345 555 123"
firstnameB, lastnameB,"+49 12345 555 124"
firstnameC, lastnameC,"+49 12345 555 125"
firstnameD, lastnameD,"+49 12345 555 126"
```

So, and I would like to display it like that way (firstnameA, lastnameA in one row and the three digit number in the second row:

```
firstnameA, lastnameA              123
firstnameB, lastnameB              124
firstnameC, lastnameC              125
firstnameD, lastnameD              126
```

till yet I have that code:

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$phonebook = fopen("database/itlocal.csv", "r");


while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {

    echo "<tr class='departmenttext'>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

How can I skip the first two lines and also cut the telephone number I'd like to have it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$lineCount = 0;
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    if ($lineCount > 1) {
        echo "<tr class='departmenttext'>";
        foreach ($line as $key => $cell) {
            if ($key == 1) {
               $cell = substr($cell, -3);
               echo '';
            }
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";

            if ($key == 1) {
                echo "</tr>\n";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    $lineCount = $lineCount + 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. for the two lines it works. so my firsr problem is totally solved. really, thanks a lot. .... but do you know any solution for my digit problem? to cut it away until the last three digits`?

Comment: using this it will cut the three digits : $cell = substr($cell, -3);
 if not try to change the index of jey from 2 to 1 for example

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem accept it to help other person with your same problem :D @SaschaDeathworm

Comment: Hi, yep, i've checked your answer as correct. but to be honest, that cell cut doesnt works completly for me. so I have to change the first key to 1. then it cuts the numbers to the three digit version. but then it won't get displayed anymore in the same row. the phone number gets pushed to the next line and looses it style (it becomes black and small). so it looks like it gets excluded from the input

Comment: same "failure". first line is the name with the correct style from css and then second line the three digit number without the correct style and not in the same line

Comment: okay, I think i got it. I had to remove those two TR's (echo '</tr><tr>';) to get it the same line. I guess its completly kewl now. thanks thanks and again thanks.

Comment: Amazing! nice catch

Comment: hey again. one short question. i am thinking about scrollbars or two rows of names + phone numbers... but for me it is impossible to do display all the names + phone numbers on two rows. would you mind to give me a hint how to solve that? because I just have this ". htmlspecialchars($cell) ." and that displays oneline. but whatever I do I can't split it to two rows so that it is like  NAME1 PHONE1 | NAME2 PHONE2  and then just the next line with NAME3 PHONE3 | NAME4 PHONE4 ....

Comment: try to create a new question with new problem and I'll try to solve It because I haven't understand well your problem now and this is another question